# Better way to get slices of a long text file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, stream, slice, filereader

I need to import a file of hundreds of lines with javascript. Each line has a fixed length of 200 chars.
A specific position and length in that line has a meaning: id, title, date, etc.

I have this code:

```
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
  const file = reader.result;
  const allLines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  allLines.forEach((line) => {
    if(line.length){
      var data = {
        type: line.slice(0, 1),
        id: line.slice(1, 7),
        title: line.slice(7, 27),
        date: line.slice(27, 35),
        // ...
        // ...
        status: line.slice(199,200) 
      }
    }
  });
};

reader.readAsText(fileToImport);
```

I think this way with many slice() is inefficient. There is a better way to do that? Maybe I could stream the data somehow, use cursors (if they exist in JS) or something.

Comment: It looks like you should study the performance of the code before trying to optimize.

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, good advice